# ArrayList <Word> cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, android, arraylist

This is probably a simple question and I have seen similar questions asked but I  don't see how their responses apply to mine, so I apologize in advance but I am getting this error:
Incompatible types:  ArrayList  cannot be converted to int

This is for an assignment and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

        // Create a list of words
        ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        words.add(new Word("one", "lutti"));
        words.add(new Word("two", "otiiko"));
        words.add(new Word("three", "tolookosu"));
        words.add(new Word("four", "oyyisa"));
        words.add(new Word("five", "massokka"));
        words.add(new Word("six", "temmokka"));
        words.add(new Word("seven", "kenekaku"));
        words.add(new Word("eight", "kawinta"));
        words.add(new Word("nine", "wo’e"));
        words.add(new Word("ten", "na’aacha"));

        // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
        // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);

        // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
        // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
        // activity_numbers.xml layout file.
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
        // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I am getting the error on this line:

```
WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);
```

Here is my adapter code:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by danle on 7/25/2016.
 */
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
    public WordAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public WordAdapter(NumbersActivity context, int resource, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, resource, words);
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int` is a primitive type and you can not assign an object of type `ArrayList <Word>` to it.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: public WordAdapter(NumbersActivity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, words);
    }

Comment: specifically on words in (context,words).

Comment: Would you please post our adapter code. @DannyHiggins

Comment: just copy paste my code and enjoy @DannyHiggins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your second constructor. There is no super constructor for `ArrayAdapter` that takes just a context and an `ArrayList<Word>`. So that super is calling `(Context, int)` and trying convert words to an integer resource.

```
public WordAdapter(NumbersActivity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
    super(context, words);
}
```

your constructor should be

```
public WordAdapter(NumbersActivity context, int resource, ArrayList<Word> words) {
    super(context, resource, words);
}
```

Comment: Probably it should also reference `Context` instead of the Concrete Activity.

Comment: Glad to have helped, please mark the answer as accepted in case other people have the same problem.

Comment: that fixed that issue but immediately brought about the same error code on my numbersactivity.     I have edited the code from my numbersactivity into my original question. Could you take a look at it for me?

Comment: You need to pass the layout of the list row into your adapter. WordsAdapter(this, R.layout.something, words)

Comment: I apologize but this is over my head.  Where do I put this?

Comment: WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words); needs to be adapter = new WordAdapter(this, R.layout.your_layout_file, words);

Comment: @Ben I am getting cannot resolve symbol adapter now.

Comment: There should be a check mark under the down arrow to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
public WordAdapter(NumbersActivity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, words);
    }
```

Tries to set the ressource-ID with the object "words".

Use the following constructor:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

[See Also](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor

```
public WordAdapter(NumbersActivity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, words);
}
```

is calling `super(context, words);` which does not have a direct match in Super class. So it is getting matched against `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)`. hence the error of assigning and `ArrayList` to `int` issue. You should use following constructor from Super class

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)`

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

So you need to replace above mentioned code with

```
 public WordAdapter(NumbersActivity context, int resource, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, resource, words);
 }
```

And call it like this:

```
WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this,<resource id for list item android.R.layout.xxx>, words);
```

Comment: do I paste over my current constructor with the constructor that you suggest?

Comment: Yes, you need to modify your existing constructor by using suggested 3-argument super constructor

Answer (score 0):

Just change your adapter to this :

```
public class WordAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Word> items=new ArrayList();

    Context mContext;

    public WordAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<Word> words) {
        items=words;
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Word mWord=items.get(position);
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take me a full day to find my error ,but your is in your file wordAdapter:

It should be like that:

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {


    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
        // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
        // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
        // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
        super(context, 0, words);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.simple_list_item_3, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
        TextView mongolTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.mongol_text_view);
        // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the name TextView
        mongolTextView.setText(currentWord.getmMongolTranslation());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
        TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
        // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
        // set this text on the number TextView
        defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getmDefaultTranslation());


        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
        // so that it can be shown in the ListView
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```